# Update a folder custom property after a searchresult

Tags: pnp, pnpjs

In my SharePoint site, I have my document library "MyDocs", and I have a list of companies "Companies"

I added a new lookup column to the document Library "Company" to link a folder to a Company.

Now, I search all folders for company name in title, and I should update the CompanyId.

I didn't found how can I obtain the folder ID to update it, like this:

```
const searchResults = await sp.search(companyName)

const myFolder: ISearchResult = searchResults.PrimarySearchResults[0];
const folderId = myFolder.WorkId//DocId; // ???? WHAT HERE

// update myFolder.CompanyId from item.companyId
const folderItem = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyDocs").items.getById(folderId);
await folderItem.update({
  CompanyId: item.companyId
});
```

Comment: You need SharePoint default item ID column value in `folderId` variable. Check if `myFolder` result returns `Id` or `ID` property in the response and use it. Something like: `const folderId = myFolder.Id;` OR `const folderId = myFolder.ID;`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: this is the most evident think i could try, there is no id

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP there is absolutly no docs on that SearchResult. the doc is soo poor that is like there is no doc.

Comment: You can select specific managed properties from search like: `const searchResults = await sp.search(
 {
  Querytext: companyName
  SelectProperties: ["Title", "ListItemID", "Author"]
 }
)`. Try using this `ListItemID` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP the returning ISearchResult object has no property "ListItemID", there is any doc on what is ISearchResult is and what properties are what.

Comment: You have to use the search call as mentioned above and then get ID using something like: `const folderId = myFolder.ListItemID`. `ListItemID` is the "string" managed property. You may need to convert it to "number" type.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP see my onw answer to that question

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Ganesh suggested to me to include SelectProperties, I did the following

```
const searchSettings = { SelectProperties: ["Title", "ListItemID"] };
const query = SearchQueryBuilder(mySearch, searchSettings);

// then after search

const myFolder: ISearchResult = searchResults.PrimarySearchResults[0];
const folderId = (myFolder as any).ListItemID as number// WorkId//DocId;
```

I cry over the very poor documentation on the topic, there is nothing to read to understand that behaviour.